# Date conversion in SQL script

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have sql file with data exported from Oracle DB. I need to convert it to MSSQL format.
Right now I'm struggling with date conversion.

Sample line:

```
Insert into "schema_version" ("installed_rank","version","description","type","script","checksum","installed_by","installed_on","execution_time","success") values (1,'1.0','schema','SQL','V1_0__schema.sql',-839661171,'HYP_EPMO2',to_timestamp('11/09/18 15:42:42,712463000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS,FF'),496,1);
```

I need to convert `to_timestamp('11/09/18 15:42:42,712463000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS,FF')` into `2018-09-11T15:42:42`.
How I can do it in easy way?
I have same problem in few tables, so can't tokenize by column number.
So far I was using `sed` for other conversions but can't find good approach here.
I was also trying `awk` (found way to replace date pattern) but I don't know how to extract only date from line and paste it back,

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sed has a `-E` option to enable EREs (e.g. GNU and BSD seds):

```
$ sed -E "s:(.*)to_timestamp\('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ([^,]+)[^)]+\):\1'20\4-\2-\3T\5':" file
Insert into "schema_version" ("installed_rank","version","description","type","script","checksum","installed_by","installed_on","execution_time","success") values (1,'1.0','schema','SQL','V1_0__schema.sql',-839661171,'HYP_EPMO2','2018-11-09T15:42:42',496,1);
```

otherwise with any sed:

```
$ sed "s:\(.*\)to_timestamp('\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\) \([^,]*\)[^)]*):\1'20\4-\2-\3T\5':" file
Insert into "schema_version" ("installed_rank","version","description","type","script","checksum","installed_by","installed_on","execution_time","success") values (1,'1.0','schema','SQL','V1_0__schema.sql',-839661171,'HYP_EPMO2','2018-11-09T15:42:42',496,1);
```